# Mi virtualhost apunta al dashboard

Tags: xampp, localhost, configuración, virtualhost, crm

Estoy trabajando con un CRM propio con laravel mix y php. Intento montar el host virtual pero me redirige al dashboard.

**apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts**

```
#localhost
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "c:/xampp/htdocs"
</VirtualHost>

#spanar
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName spanar.local
    DocumentRoot "c:/xampp/htdocs/spanar"
</VirtualHost>
```

**DRIVERS/HOSTS**

```
127.0.0.1        spanar.local
::1              spanar.local
```

**apache/conf/httpd**

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

...

LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Answer (score 0):

Y tu config no debería ser igual a la de Laravel normal??

Me refiero a donde apunta el VH, porque yo siempre los hago así:

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
# La primer línea va arriba de todos los VH
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\community\public"
    ServerName community.test
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\community\public">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Acá hay algunas cosas, para cada proyecto me ha tocado poner esas mismas líneas de código, así tal cual las vez ahí. Tengo mis reservas con la primer línea pero igual, así me ha funcionado.

Si el puerto es el 80, no deberías especificarlo, bastaría con el *. Y por ultimo, se apunta a public, no a root.

En el host de windows `127.0.0.1    community.test`

Prueba si te funciona así.

Comment: Mi archivo **index.php** se encuentra en la carpeta root del proyecto, por eso apunta ahí. He probado incluso de crear una directorio nuevo en htdocs e incluir solo un index.php para ver si me carga ese, y me dirige igualmente al dashboard de xampp.

Comment: Osea, es al dash de XAMPP que te redirige? No es al de tu App?? Probaste con mi código??